# rails, nested associated models AR query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, associations

i have a User model and a Post model. User has_many Posts; Post belongs_to User.

I want to create a table that lists a User and the total number of Posts per user as long as the post's public_flag is 't'. Is this possible directly in the view?

In my controller:

```
@users = User.all
```

In my view:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<%= user.posts.size%>
<% end %>
```

Of course, this gets ALL of the user's posts regardless if the public_flag is true. Is there any way to set a condition in the View, or will I need to do something fancy in the controller (AR Query?).

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can daisy-chain restrictions for models, like so:

```
user.posts.where(:public_flag => 't').count
```

The advantage of using `count` over `size` is that instead of pulling all the posts into memory and counting them, ActiveRecord will execute a count query against the database and save a lot of processing.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks, Jaime! And thanks also for the extra note on count vs size. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
user.posts.find_by_public_flag(true).count
```

Comment: This solution pulls all the matching records from the database, forcing rails to instantiate objects for them all, just to count them. Using `count` instead of `size fixes this.

Comment: agree, just saw your answer.. count would be better :) I have updated the answer.